# Combine 2 arrays into 2d array without losing data

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have 2 arrays and want to combine into third array with one array as key and another as value. I tried to use array_combine(), but the function will eliminate all the repeated keys, so I want the result array as a 2d array. The sample array is as below:

```
$keys = {0,1,2,0,1,2,0,1,2};
$values = {a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i};
 $result = array(
    [0]=>array(0=>a,1=>b,2=>c),
    [1]=>array(0=>d,1=>e,2=>f),
    [2]=>array(0=>g,1=>h,2=>i)
 );
//What i am using right now is: 
$result = array_combine($keys,$values);
```

But it only returns array(0=>g,2=>h,3=>i). Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: obviously. Because **array must have unique keys/index**

Comment: yes, i know that, so I intended to convert into 2d array like above. But i dont know how

Comment: your values are same `0,1,2,0,1,2`, and when they converted to keys they got over-written by the latest value

Comment: I knew how they are over-written, but what I want to ask is how to split 3 keys of each as a smaller array in a 2d result array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like below:-

```
<?php

$keys = array(0,1,2,0,1,2,0,1,2);
$values = array('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i');

$values = array_chunk($values,count(array_unique($keys)));

foreach($values as &$value){
   $value = array_combine(array_unique($keys),$value);
}

print_r($values);
```

https://eval.in/859753

Comment: Sorry to bother you, but Is there anyway I could chunk the array $values by a condition in $keys. For example the array $key is {0,1,2,4,5,2,6,7,4,2}. How can I chunk the array $values whenever $keys = 2?

Comment: @Tedxxxx  please ask a new question. You will for-sure get an answer. you can shar that question link to me also. I will check if possible and try to give an answer.

Comment: this is my new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46169332/combine-2-arrays-into-a-third-array-with-inconstant-unique-keys-from-one-array

Answer (score 1):

Yes the above is working and i give upvote too for this but i dont know why you combine into the foreach loop its not necessary. The results are given in only in second line. Can you describe?

```
<?php
 $keys = array(0,1,2,0,1,2,0,1,2);
 $values = array('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i');
 $v = array_chunk($values,count(array_unique($keys)));
 echo "<pre>";print_r($v);
?>
```

https://eval.in/859759

Comment: Is there anyway we can chunk the array by a condition, for example, chunk when key = 2?

Comment: it's because he want `$keys` as an array keys. what happen if `$keys = array(2,3,5,2,3,5);` output need to be:- `Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [2] => a
            [3] => b
            [5] => c
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [2] => d
            [3] => e
            [5] => f
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [2] => g
            [3] => h
            [5] => i
        )

)`

Comment: @AlivetoDie not need to add but there is no need i think. Why we write extra lines of code?

Comment: @AnandPandey  check my comment above.See here:- https://eval.in/859765 (mine) and https://eval.in/859766 (yours)

Comment: @AlivetoDie: i dont undeerstand the difference the output is same of us.

Comment: @AlivetoDie: Oh yeah i see the difference

Comment: @AnandPandey  because if he don't want based on `$keys`then what's the significance of that extra array?I hope now you got my point?

Comment: @AlivetoDie: yeah i see and understand now :)

Comment: Because in my data, it has different numbers of unique keys, so I want to chunk by a condition when key equal to a value. Is there any function i could do that?

Answer (score 0):

As a more flexible/robust solution, push key-value pairs into new rows whenever the key's value is already in the currently targeted row.  In other words, there will never be an attempt to write a key into a row that already contains that particular key.

This can be expected to be highly efficient because there are no iterated function calls ...no function calls at all, really.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Yg0H9))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($keys as $i => $key) {
    $counter[$key] = ($counter[$key] ?? -1) + 1;
    $result[$counter[$key]][$key] = $values[$i];
}
var_export($result);
```