# Combine 2 arrays into a third array with inconstant unique keys from one array

Tags: php, arrays, unique

I have 2 arrays as below.

```
$keys = [1,2,3,4-1,99,1,2,3,4-1,4-2,4-3,99,1,2,3,4-1,4-2,99]
$values = [a,b,c,d,x,a1,b1,c1,d1,e,g,x,a2,b2,c2,d2,e,x]
```

I want to combine into an array like:

```
$result = array(
  [0]=>array(1=>a,2=>b,3=>c,4-1=>d,99=>x),
  [1]=>array(1=>a1,2=>b1,3=>c1,4-1=>d1,4-2=>e,4-3=>g,99=>x),
  [2]=>array(1=>a2,2=>b2,3=>c2,4-1=>d2,4-2=>e,99=>x
);
```

The rule is break anytime $key=99.
Currently, I tried to use array_chunk but the syntax only allows me to chunk the array by the number of unique keys, which is not constant in my example.
Any advice?

Comment: Add what you tried. `$keys` and `$values` are not arrays!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write a custom script which combines these two arrays by your logic.

You need to fetch each key from the `$keys` array and combine it with the same element by position from the `$values` array.

Example:

```
<?php
$keys = ['1', '2', '3', '4-1', '99', '1', '2', '3', '4-1', '4-2', '4-3', '99', '1', '2', '3', '4-1', '4-2', '99'];
$values = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'x', 'a1', 'b1', 'c1', 'd1', 'e', 'g', 'x', 'a2', 'b2', 'c2', 'd2', 'e', 'x'];

$i = 0;
$result = [];
foreach ($keys as $index => $key) {
    if (empty($result[$i]))
        $result[$i] = [$key => $values[$index]];
    else
        $result[$i][$key] = $values[$index];

    if ($key == 99)
        ++$i;
}

print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use foreach loop to achieve this

```
$keys = ["1","2","3","4-1","99","1","2","3","4-1","4-2","4-3","99","1","2","3","4-1","4-2","99"];
$values = ["a","b","c","d","x","a1","b1","c1","d1","e","g","x","a2","b2","c2","d2","e","x"];
$new_array = array();
$split_at = "99";
$i = 0;
foreach ($keys as $key => $value) {
    $new_array[$i][$value] =$values[$key];

    if($split_at == $value){
     $i++;
    }
}

print_r($new_array);
```

[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/uAsjN)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of conditionally incrementing a counter to determine where data gets pushed into an array, row data can be populated by pushing references into the result array.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/PCbUu))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($keys as $i => $k) {
    if (!isset($ref)) {
        $result[] = &$ref;
    }
    $ref[$k] = $values[$i];
    if ($k == 99) {
        unset($ref);
    }
}

var_export($result);
```

---

If you want to maintain a counter variable, that can look like this: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/ZhKNL))

```
$counter = 0;
$result = [];
foreach ($keys as $i => $k) {
    $result[$counter][$k] = $values[$i];
    if ($k == 99) {
        ++$counter;
    }
}

var_export($result);
```